# Remove special characters in rows in a Data Frame

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a dataframe with a row called `indicator` that have numbers mixed with letters before the actual observation (content) i.e. in the below DF, the mixed letters and numbers are

```
6.2-, S1.1, S3.1- & I1.1
```

Actual DF

```
indicator <- c("6.2- Total number customers per month (average)","S1.1 Total of unique users served per month", "S3.1- Volume of merchandise sold per month", 
               "I1.1 Quantity of bags received per month.")
amount <- c(12, 45, 44, 67)

DF <- data.frame(indicator, amount)


> DF
                                        indicator amount
1 6.2- Total number customers per month (average)     12
2     S1.1 Total of unique users served per month     45
3      S3.1- Volume of merchandise sold per month     44
4       I1.1 Quantity of bags received per month.     67
```

How do I remove the mixed numbers and letters using either `stringr` or `regex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the indicator is always at the beginning and followed by a white space, you could do this to remove everything from the beginning to the first space.

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

DF$indicator <- DF$indicator  %>% str_remove_all("^.*? ")
```

```
> DF
                                   indicator amount
1 Total number customers per month (average)     12
2     Total of unique users served per month     45
3       Volume of merchandise sold per month     44
4       Quantity of bags received per month.     67
```

- `^` anchors to the beginning of the string
- `.*` matches everything (until the white space)
- `?` stops the regex at the first white space instead of the last white space

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub()` as follows:

```r
DF$indicator <- sub("^[A-Z]*\\d(?:\\.\\d+)*-?\\s+", "", DF$indicator)
DF

                                   indicator amount
1 Total number customers per month (average)     12
2     Total of unique users served per month     45
3       Volume of merchandise sold per month     44
4       Quantity of bags received per month.     67
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used:

- `^` from the start of the indicator
- `[A-Z]*` match zero or more leading capital letters
- `\d` match a digit
- `(?:\.\d+)*` followed by dot and digits, zero or more times
- `-?` match an optional ending dash
- `\s+` match one or more whitespace characters